# Why when finding with a significance level $\alpha$ a confidence interval for the mean, the $\alpha$ appears as $\alpha/2$?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

I just can't get some things in the reasoning that gives us the confidence interval for the mean. I am going to state the argumentation and let me know where am I wrong.

Given a sample $X_1,...X_n$ from a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, I want to calculate a confidence interval with a significance level $\alpha$ for the mean $\mu$. In order to approximate the mean, I want to consider the random variable $$T=\frac{\overline X-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$$ because this is a $t$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom (but isn't it also a $N(0,1)$? I just normalised right? Also, why exactly do I consider $T$?).

Okay so now the reasoning says that the confidence interval for $\alpha$ is $$ P(-t_{\alpha/2}\leq 
 T \leq t_{\alpha/2}) = \alpha$$
and after operating inside the brackets, we leave alone the mean $\mu$ so we end up with the confidence interval for $\mu$.

So why do we consider $t_{\alpha/2}$? Where the $\alpha/2$ comes from?

Comment: There are at least two questions here.  The $t$ distribution happens when you do not know $\sigma$ and instead estimate it from the data so $s/\sqrt{n}$ is itself a random variable (proportional to a chi distributed random variable) changing the quotient

Comment: $\alpha/2$ comes from having two tails, though I think you actually want $P(t_{\alpha/2}\leq  T \leq t_{1-\alpha/2}) = 1-\alpha$.  So for example if $\alpha =0.05$ this gives you a $95\%$ probability of being in that interval $[t_{0.025},t_{0.975}]$ if the null hypothesis is correct.  You want the probability of being below the interval plus the probability of being above the  interval to be $\alpha$, so if you split this evenly then then you want each of those to be $\alpha/2$

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the answer but I am afraid I don't understand many things here still. Can you recommend me a nice statistics book to review these concepts from zero? Many thanks